# Symfony - EasyAdmin - Add and remove functions are ignored from AssociationField

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I use the last version of EasyAdmin and my `add` and `remove` functions are ignored when I submit the form:

`Ambiance` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vehicule", mappedBy="ambiance")
 */
protected Collection $vehicules;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->vehicules = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addVehicule(Vehicule $vehicule): self
{
    if (!$this->vehicules->contains($vehicule)) {
        $this->vehicules[] = $vehicule;
        $vehicule->setAmbiance($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeVehicule(Vehicule $vehicule): void
{
    if (!$this->vehicules->contains($vehicule)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->vehicules->removeElement($vehicule);
}

public function getVehicules()
{
    return $this->vehicules;
}

public function setVehicules($vehicules): void
{
    $this->vehicules = $vehicules;
}
```

Yet my Doctrine mapping is valid..

My EasyAdmin form in `AmbianceCrudController.php`:

```
'vehicules' => AssociationField::new('vehicules', 'Véhicules'),
```

It generates a `multiple select2` but when I add vehicles and submit my form, no data is inserted.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
AssociationField::new('vehicules')
```

by

```
AssociationField::new('vehicules', 'Véhicules')->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm strugling with the same problem, but I found already bits of the puzzle that could be helpful:

- in my experience, it seems that the owning side of the association (the one that has the foreign key in the database) results in an edit form that persists the change.
- the other side ignores the change completely
- the setters and getters, and addABC and removeABC methods seem indeed to be skipped for reasons that are unclear to me as well.

I hope you can find a solution with the hint that the crudcontroller other side in the relationship, I think Vehicules in your case.